# Operaciones con Diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo el siguiente problema: Escriba un programa que reciba una lista de votos por diferentes candidatos y calcule cuál es el candidato ganador. Si hay un empate el programa debe imprimir la palabra EMPATE. En caso contrario, debe imprimir el nombre del candidato ganador.

he desarrollado el siguiente código:

```
n = int(input())
candidatos = {'Juan':0, 'María':0,'Pedro':0}
for candidato in range(n):
    candidato = input()
    candidatos[candidato] += 1
ganador = 0 
for candidato, conteo in candidatos.items():
    if conteo >= ganador:
        if conteo > ganador:
            ganador = conteo
            ganador_1 = candidato
        else:
            print('empate')
            break
```

mi pregunta es, no se como poder imprimir cual es el candidato ganador final, o en el caso que hay un empate tengo un problema que me imprime empate sin importar que haya otro candidato con mayor votación

les agradezco su amable colaboración

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo agregar un poco de comentarios a tu código para que podamos utilizarlo y ayudarte a encontrar el problema. Recuerda que al desarrollar software el programa será utilizado por alguien más y debe tener instrucciones claras de como utilizar el programa que creaste

Comment: Buen día, tienes toda la razón, agradezco tu valiosa ayuda y atenderé a tu sugerencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El código que creaste es casi correcto

El `for` lo puedes utilizar para evaluar quién es el ganador pero no debes imprimir el resultado estando dentro del ciclo `for` porque aún no sabes si terminaste de recorrer la lista de candidatos o no, por lo tanto el `print` con el nombre del candidato ganador o la palabra "empate" debe ir afuera del ciclo `for`

```
n = int(input())
candidatos = {'Juan':0, 'María':0,'Pedro':0}
for candidato in range(n):
    candidato = input()
    candidatos[candidato] += 1
ganador = 0 
for candidato, conteo in candidatos.items():
    if conteo >= ganador:
        if conteo > ganador:
            ganador = conteo
            ganador_1 = candidato
        else:
            ganador_1="empate"

print(ganador_1)
```

Comment: si funciono el condigo de acuerdo a la sugerencia de sacar el print del ciclo for . excelente.

Comment: @CesarCepeda si esta respuesta resolvio tu pregunta, deberias marcarla como la respuesta correcta. Esto ayuda a que tu pregunta pueda ser vista por mas personas que tal vez tengan un problema similar al que tuviste.

Comment: Ok , muchas gracias.